# Reorder string using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, replace, location

I want to bring the first occurrence of a date or in general a regular expression to the beginning of my text:

Example:
`"I went out on 1 sep 2012 and it was better than 15 jan 2012"`
and I want to get
`"1 sep 2012, I went out on and it was better than 15 jan 2012"`

I was thinking about replacing `"1 sep 2012"` with `",1 sep 2012,"` and then cutting the string from `","` but I don't know what to write instead of `replace_with`:

```
line = re.sub(r'\d+\s(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\s\d{4}', 'replace_with', line, 1)
```

any help?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: You're not using enough capture groups...

Comment: Forget about Python for the moment. Please look through some regex tutorials. The first argument that you have in `re.sub()` above won't get you what you want.

Comment: Although the python re doc is very good http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "I went out on 1 sep 2012 and it was better than 15 jan 2012"
>>> r = re.compile('(^.*)(1 sep 2012 )(.*$)')
>>> r.sub(r'\2\1\3',s)
'1 sep 2012 I went out on and it was better than 15 jan 2012'
```

Brackets capture parts of the string:

```
(^.*)          # Capture everything from the start of the string
(1 sep 2012 )  # Upto the part we are interested in (captured)
(.*$)          # Capture everything else
```

Then just reorder the capture groups in the substitution `` `\2\1\3' `` *note:* to reference the capture groups requires a raw string `r'\2\1\3'`. The second group in my example is just the literal string `(1 sep 2012 )` but of course this can be any regexp such as the one you created (with an extra `\s` on the end):

```
(\d+\s(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\s\d{4}\s)

>>> r = re.compile(r'(^.*)(\d+\s(?:aug|sep|oct|nov)\s\d{4}\s)(.*$)')
>>> r.sub(r'\2\1\3',s)
'1 sep 2012 I went out on and it was better than 15 jan 2012'
```

From [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

> When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change.